# Store `ggplot` call in a `data.frame` (or alternative) and then evaluate it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to store `ggplot` calls in a `data.frame` (or alternative) and evaluate it later.

An example:

```
define <- function(df, call) {
  df[nrow(df) + 1, ] <- call
  df
} 

plot <- function(df, index) {
  eval(parse(text = df$plots[index]))
}

df <- data.frame(plots = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- define(df, "ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 2))")
df <- define(df, "ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 2, xend = 2, yend = 1))")

plot(df, 1)
plot(df, 2)
```

This sort of works and plots:

[image]
[image]

But there are some **issues**:

1. I'd like define the calls without '"' signs. Like `define(df, ggplot() + geom_..)`.
2. I'd rather store the calls as `call` objects.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also capture the expression as expression (`enexpr`) and store as string

```
define <- function(df, call) {

    df[nrow(df) + 1, ] <- rlang::as_label(rlang::enexpr(call))
   df

}

plot <- function(df, index) {
  eval(parse(text = df[["plots"]][index]))
}


df <- data.frame(plots = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- define(df, ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 2)))
df <- define(df, ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 2, xend = 2, yend = 1)))

plot(df, 1)
plot(df, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a list for this case. `data.frame`s are a bit tricky when storing unevaluated content (because underneath they contain more information than just the call). Lists are more versatile (and easier to use in this context):

```
#saves the unevaluated call
define <- function(mylist, call) {
  mylist[[length(mylist) + 1]] <- substitute(call)
  mylist
} 

#evaluates the call
ploteval <- function(mylist, index) {
  eval(mylist[[index]])
}

mylist <- list()

mylist <- define(mylist, ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 2)))
mylist <- define(mylist, ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 2, xend = 2, yend = 1)))


ploteval(mylist, 1)
ploteval(mylist, 2)
```

This will work.

[image]

[image]

As a short explanation, substitute will store the unevaluated call, which will then be evaluated with `ploteval`. It is also not a good idea to overwrite `plot` so I gave it a new name `ploteval`.